# i18next.use and all other properties are undefined with webpack craco config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, i18next, craco

I'm migrating my create-react-application to craco and upgraded react-scripts from v3.4.1 to v4.03. After react-script version update and craco i18next stopped working.

```
/* craco.config.js */
const path = require(`path`);
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack');
filenames = fs.readdirSync( path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'));


module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    alias: filenames.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc[path.parse(curr).name] = path.resolve(__dirname, `src/${curr}`)
        return acc;
    }, {}),
  },
};
```

Here's my i18next.js file which is imported in src/index.js

```
const i18n = require('i18next'); 
// import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
// not like to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide    
// for passing in lng and translations on init


const languages = ['eng','spa','fra','por','rus','ara','per','hin','cht','jpn','chi'];

i18n
  // load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'eng',
    debug: false,
    whitelist: languages,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
  });


export default i18n;
```

I'm getting i18n.use is not a function error with the new craco config. it was working fine before migrating to craco.

[image]

Comment: Can you console log i18n? Also import vs. require

Comment: I tried both import and require, on console log i18n I get empty Object like {}.

Comment: I'm assuming that upgrading react-scripts from v3.4.1 to react-scripts to v4.0.3 is the cause of problem

Answer (score 0):

somehow

```
import i18n from '../node_modules/i18next';
```

is working fine, but these are not working

```
const i18n = require('i18next'); 
import i18n from 'i18next';
import * as i18n from 'i18next';
```